# Does a struct implement all the interfaces that one of their embedded type implement?

Tags: struct, go

I have this example

```
// embed project main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    A1 int
    A2 int
}

func (a A) Incr() int {
    a.A1++
    return a.A1
}

type B struct {
    A
    D int
}

type C interface {
    Incr() int
}

func Add(c C) {
    d := c.Incr()
    fmt.Println(d)
}

func main() {
    var s B
    s.Incr() //B has Incr
    Add(s)
}
```

Using this example i wanted to check whether B implement interface C or not. In this example Add accept s (type B) as input. **B implement C**.

But when i change Incr() method from original to

```
func (a *A) Incr() int {
    a.A1++
    return a.A1
}
```

It compiler gives the error

> ./main.go:35: cannot use s (type B) as type C in argument to
>   AddContent:   B does not implement C (Incr method has pointer receiver)

So i am still confused whether a struct implement all the interface that one of their embedded type implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your struct implements the method set of the embedded type.

However, when you change the signature of `Incr` to `func (a *A) Incr() int`, you need a pointer for the receiver of that method. `A` itself doesn't implement `Incr` when it has a pointer receiver.

The reason the `s.Incr()` call works, is that the `s` value is addressable, and Go automatically references it for the method call. When you pass `s` to `Add`, you're attempting to convert it to a `C` interface, the value would no longer be addressable, and the `Incr` method isn't in the method set.

In this case, you can either change the embedded type to `*A`,

```
type B struct {
    *A
    D int
}
```

take the address of `s` at the call site

```
Add(&s)
```

or make `s` a pointer (`*B`):

```
s := &B{}
Add(s)
```

The [relevent portion of the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also
>     includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an anonymous field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

Answer (score 2):

> If S contains an anonymous field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
>
> If S contains an anonymous field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include
> promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

B embedded A, so method sets of B include protomoted methods with receiver A, but does not include *A

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a observation that this also works with interface references, but only within the same package.

Pseudocode:

```
package A

type MyInterface {...}
type Foo { myif MyInterface }

func X1(one MyInterface) {
    ...
}

// This does work, even though Foo doesn't explicitly implement MyInterface
func X2() {
    o := Foo{}
    X1(o)
}

package B

import "A"

// this one does not compile: A.Foo does not implement A.MyInterface
func X2() {
    o2 := A.Foo{}
    A.X1(o2)
}
```

It also doesn't seem to matter whether "myif" is exported or private. Just whether the calling code is within the declaring package or somewhere else.

Is that explicitly specified ?
Can anyone point to the corresponding paragraph in the language spec ?

--mtx